# Support of an effective Cartier vs Weil divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a Noetherian locally factorial integral scheme so that $\operatorname{Ca}(X)\cong Z^1(X)$. An effective divisor could be thought of as a global section $D\in \Gamma(X,\mathscr{K}^*/\mathscr{O}^*)$, an effective Weil divisor $D = \sum \mu_Y(D) Y$, or an ideal sheaf $\mathscr{I}_D$ which is locally principal. Consequently, there are three reasonable ways to define the support of $D$.

$$
S_1 := \{P\in X\;|\;D_P\not\in \mathscr{O}_P^*\}
$$
$$
S_2 := \{P\in X\;|\;\dim \mathscr{O}_P = 1,\,D_P\in m_P\} ^- 
$$
$$
S_3 := \operatorname{Min.Ass.Pt}(\mathscr{O}_X/\mathscr{I}_D)^-
$$

The first definition comes from the support of a global section of an abelian sheaf. The second definition is to take the closure of all prime Weil divisors where $D$ has a nonzero coefficients. The third definition is to take the closure of the (minimal) associated points of the coherent sheaf $\mathscr{O}_X/\mathscr{I}_D$.

> Are these the same?

It is clear to me that $S_2\subset S_1$, what about the rest inclusions?